# Subtheme not applying to category pages

Tags: parent-child-theme

I recently installed a theme I purchased (called Venedor) on the latest magento ce install.  I'd been manually adjusting the css file of the theme until I recently discovered that magento allows for subthemes, which sounds great since it would help prevent me from having to keep track of the changed files for future updates.

Unfortunately I seem to have run into a strange problem.  I was able to create my subtheme files in /skin/frontend/venedor/my_subtheme, and it looks like the changes work perfectly on the home page of the site, as well as on the product pages.  But for some strange reason the subtheme changes aren't working at all on the category pages, and magento seems to be reverting back to the Venedor default theme.  Is there some reason why this might happen?  I'm not sure if there's some sort of configuration on the backend I'm missing, or if there might be some sort of problem with the Venedor theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that a Custom Design was somehow set for each of the categories under Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Your Category -> Custom Design -> Custom Design.  I had to set them all back to the "Please Select" option in order to get it working correctly.